# Is anything like LAG() or LEAD() in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, lag, lead

I want to get the next row value in current row. Just like `LEAD()` does in latest SQL Server. But I am currently using SQL Server 2000. And I don't have any other option.

Actual scenario is:

**TableRule**:

```
#   HeadNo | NextHeadNo |     NoFrom
-----------+------------+------------
1    AA    |    AB      |        1
2    AB    |    AC      |        1
3    AC    |    AX      |        1
4    AD    |    AE      |        1   ****and so on
```

I want to update `NextHeadNo` value based on next value on `HeadNo`.

So as per the data `Row-3` should get update `AX ➪ AD`.

I have around 1000 records to update for single time.

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: You can join with same table (self join) on tb1.id = tb2.id+1.....

Comment: @SQLCoder: Actually there has not any Id column in table

Comment: Do you know on the basis of which column you want to pick next value?

Comment: You need to have a column to order on the basis of which you will pick the next record.

Comment: @SQLCoder: as shown in sample, take next value of `ORDER BY Head_No`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like following using a subquery.

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 headno 
        FROM   @table T2 
        WHERE  T2.headno > T1.headno 
        ORDER  BY headno) NextHeadNo 
FROM   @table T1 
ORDER  BY headno
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/AFTKC56401)

To update, you can try like following.

```
UPDATE T1 SET NextHeadNo= 
       (SELECT TOP 1 headno 
        FROM   @table T2 
        WHERE  T2.headno > T1.headno 
        ORDER  BY headno)  
FROM   @table T1
```

**Edit:**

> but in last row getting NULL, So i want to give its reference to
>   first row. how can i do that?

I suggest you write a seperate update statement instead of writing `CASE WHEN` like following.

```
update t
set t.NextHeadNo =
 (
  select top 1 HeadNo from @table order by HeadNo
 )
from @table t
where t.NextHeadNo is null
```

Comment: thanks, it's worked. but in last row getting NULL, So i want to give its reference to first row. how can i do that?

Comment: You an write a separate update or put a case expression in the same quey

Comment: @jap_jap, i have updated the answer, you can have a look.